# C# 2010 Microsoft Chart 4.0 Control has no ChartType Property?

Tags: c#, charts

I want to draw a few charts in c# and used the chart control you can find in the toolbox/data.
But i am not able to change the chart type so something else, i can not find any property to change it from vertical bars to something else like a pie chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ChartType` is a property of a `Series`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.charttype.aspx), not of a `Chart`.

Comment: Thank you! It did never occur to me to look there.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [ChartType Property of Series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.charttype.aspx) and you can set chart type using [SeriesChartType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties window in that you will get Series property click on it in that you will get "Chart" property. where you can change chart type(bar,pie,line etc.)